# How to check if the current locale uses 24-hour clock in Android?

Tags: android

I have a time picker dialog in my app. This works just fine, but I'd like to switch between the 12-hour and 24-hour picker dialogs based on the current locale. How do I find out which clock is used?

The dialog itself is launched like this:

```
boolean use24HourClock = true; // This i'd like to get from the locale
new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {

    }
}, 12, 00, use24HourClock).show();
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
boolean use24HourClock = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getApplicationContext());
```

Returns **true** if user preference is set to **24-hou**r format.

See more about DateFormat [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat(android.content.Context))

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot the user can set it either way independent of the locale. This works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
public static boolean usesAmPm(Locale locale)
{
    String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
    FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.MEDIUM, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
    return pattern.contains("a");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I want to populate the boolean variable based on how the clock should be shown.

Comment: This is requiring Joda?